# is か with volitional form also considered crude/rude

Tags: grammar

So, i read this, [Usage of 'か' in short sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/35670/usage-of-%E3%81%8B-in-short-sentences). And they say that か in short form is considered crude, or rude. So would saying something like 行こうか be more or less crude than 行こう？

Answer (score 1):

- 行くか meaning "Wanna go?" or "So you're going, huh?" does sound crude and blunt. It's mainly used by stereotypical obstinate men in fiction.
- 行くか meaning "So let's go now" or "I will go now" sounds a little masculine but not crude. It's commonly used between friends.
- か after 行こう just adds a nuance of "will we?", and it's not crude at all.